# how to reduce image from 16GB SD card to fit on 8 GB card

Tags: discussion

for what reason was my post deleted? if I did something wrong, please tell me so I won't do it again. However I believe my question to be valid and inoffensive...

Comment: This question would probably be better asked on our meta site.

Comment: @DarthVader New users can't post on meta.

Comment: Only moderators can tell, regular users don't get to see deleted questions. I can only confirm that only offensive content (spam, swearing, vandalism) is supposed to be deleted outright.

Comment: Concerning your original question, I feel it might be answered [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15796/sd-image-wont-fit-on-sd-card). If that doesn't help, I suggest you [replace](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/59194/edit) your complaint with an actual question, explaining what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I have tried this using many methods, although I was going the other direction, trying to get a 16 GB system to utilize the space of a 32 GB SD card.  Never did find a methos which worked.  In the end I bought a 32 GB NOOBS and started over with that.  It works great.

Comment: This post is not deleted.  I suggest you now edit this to include your question in the body.

Answer (score 10):

Your question was deleted because it was posted as an *answer*.  A comment was left there by the moderator who deleted it, and that comment, and the ["answer that is really a question"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59192/5538) to which it is attached are still viewable by some people, including you as the owner of the deleted post (if that link isn't viewable to you, please leave a comment here).  For simplicity, I'll cut n' paste the explanation from that comment:

> Welcome to Raspberry Pi! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Not all of it may apply to your context, but very clearly the second sentence does.

When you sign up, you are invited to take [a tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).  People who actually take and read the tour receive a badge (["informed"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/informed)).  This may seem a bit silly, but since badges are public, one useful aspect of this is that it is then easy to tell who bothered to take the tour and who did not.  You did not.  I recommend you do, and not just for the silly badge ;)

I don't know what percentage of new users do take the tour, but I notice it has been awarded to ~10 people in the past day.  This can be casually correlated to the number of "questions posted as answers" we deal with daily (at least a few), the vast majority of which are posted by **new users who *DID NOT TAKE THE TOUR*.**  Huh! Interesting.

Put another way, your post was deleted because you figured it was a waste of time to:

## Read the Documentation That was Clearly Indicated To You

Sometimes failing to waste time with silly things like reading documentation results in more wasted time in the long run.

Comment: As I was the mod  who deleted your post and to add to what @goldilocks has said above. One of the reasons for deleting questions added to the answer section is to help you.  As this is a Q&A site and not a forum. Most users don't tend to read through entire threads or the portion thereof since their last visit. As a result a question placed in the answer section may never be seen by someone who could actually answer your question, and hence linger unanswered. This would not only affect you, but anyone with a similar query looking for an answer, who found your question by search engine etc.